# Problems with conditional subpattern matching

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

If I try this code:

```
<?php
 $greets1="hello jack"; $greets2="hi john";
 preg_match('/(hello )((?(?=jack)j))/',$greets1,$result);
?>
```

It writes `hello` in `$result[1]` and `j` in `$result[2]`. 
If I change the 3rd line to:

```
 preg_match('/(hello )((?(?=jack)there))/',$greets1,$result);
```

It writes nothing in both `$result[1]` and `$result[2]`. Why is that?

And also: how can I write the space character in the lookahead? I tried in many ways:

```
 preg_match('/(hello)((?(?= jack)j))/',$greets1,$result);
 preg_match('/(hello)((?(?=\ jack)j))/',$greets1,$result);
 preg_match('/(hello)((?(?=\\\ jack)j))/',$greets1,$result);
```

No one of these worked.

Comment: What is expected match?

Comment: There is no need to use conditional patterns if you aren't using them properly. So why don't you use `/(hello)(j)(?=ack)/` ? Also What you're saying doesn't make sense, you're basically saying `(?=jack) if there is "jack" then match "there"` How in the world would you match "there" if you are certain that there is "jack". So basically that's why it fails.

Comment: @HamZa but `$result[1]`, also if it fails, shouldn't contain `hello`?

Comment: @user176795 no, because you're asking the regex to match "there". But there isn't "there". Let's explain it further, you got `(hello )((?(?=jack)there))`. The first one is simple, it's just grouping "hello " in group 1. Now let's see further, `(?(?=jack)there)`: if there is jack, then match "there". In our example, there is jack, so our regex basically becomes "(hello )(there)". Now try to match "hello jack" with `/(hello )(there)/`. Impossible. \Got the idea ?

Comment: @HamZa yes. So, if only one subpattern fails, the array will be void?

Comment: About the spaces. The first one would have worked, but you forgot to add the space in front of the `j` as well. Otherwiese, you are checking that there's ` jack`, but then you try to match the `j` right away without consuming that space first. So: `/(hello)((?(?= jack) j))/` or for improved readability `/(hello)((?(?=[ ]jack)[ ]j))/` (which would also work in free spacing mode)

Comment: And about "if one subpattern fails, the array will be void": if a subpattern fails (that is not optional in some way) then the match will simply fail, and you won't get a match in the first place. No match -> no submatches. The submatches are just a byproduct of a successful match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It writes nothing in both $result[1] and $result[2]. Why is that?

Because there is no match, the match fails. You see the regex engine tries to match `hello` followed by a space and it succeeds, then it finds the conditional and checks can I match `jack`, yes I can so the condition is true and now I should try to match `there` but the engine fails to match this and the whole match attempt fails.

> how can I write the space character in the lookahead?

Just like you did in your first line, there is nothing wrong with. The problem is that the lookahead doesn't cause the regex to read any characters from the input string so after matching `hello`, the is where the regular expression is:

```
hello jack
     ^
```

Just before the space, then comes the conditional and the lookahead, the lookahead tries to match a space followed by `jack` and it succeeds, but the regular expression doesn't actually consume any characters from the input string, now we are here:

```
hello jack
     ^
```

You see the regex is still in place, it has just confirmed the lookahead and now tries to match `j` but there is a space now so it fails, so your regular expression would have worked if you changed it to this:

```
preg_match('/(hello)((?(?= jack) j))/',$greets1,$result);
                                ^ notice the space here
```

As @Hamza said in his comment, you don't need the conditional here, if you want to match a `j` only if it is part of `jack` then you can use a lookahead alone like this:

```
preg_match('/(hello)( j(?=ack\b))/',$greets1,$result);
```